# A single card is drawn at random from each of six well-shuffled decks of playing cards. Let $A$ be the event that all six cards drawn are different.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> A single card is drawn at random from each of six well-shuffled decks of playing cards. Let
> $A$ be the event that *all six cards drawn are different.*
>
> (a) Find $P(A)$.
>
> (b) Find the probability that *at least two of the drawn cards match.*

For (a), since each card is different, the probability is

$$\frac {\text{number of favorable cards}} {\text{total number of outcomes}}=\frac{52*51*50*49*48*47}{52^{6}}.$$

For (b), what's the logical thinking process to solve this?

Comment: Is it reasonable to say either $A$ happens or it does not?

Comment: @Henry yeah, think so.

Comment: That was a hint for (b)

Comment: @Henry ahh you mean to apply complement rule? I think I get what you mean. Out of curiosity, without using complement rule, is there another way to do (i.e. similar to what I did for (a))?

Comment: Yes, but it is much more complicated if you consider every pattern of matching individually (Do you want to work the probability of three of one card, two of another and one of a third, and add this to all the other possibilities?)

Comment: @Henry I see, that would be a lot more work then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $(a)$, we have $$\mathbb P(A) = \frac{\frac{52!}{(52-6)!}}{52^6} = \frac{8808975}{11881376} \approx  0.74141.$$

For $(b)$, this is simply the complementary probability:
$$
1 - \mathbb P(A) = \frac{3072401}{11881376}\approx 0.2585897.
$$